# inline-block content to behave as block

Tags: html, css, menu, block, badge

I have this [setup](https://jsfiddle.net/rmufyng4/1/)  and I would like to be able to hover on top of the LI element and have it all clickable due to the link/s it has inside.

How can I make the first link in the li item take all the possible space?

```css
a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border-left: 2px transparent solid;
  transition: background 0.10s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  /* so the badge follow the item if scrolling */
}
li:first-child {
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-left: none;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
li:first-child:hover {
  border-left: none;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
li:hover {
  border-left: 2px #F27223 solid;
  background: white;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
ul li a {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li .badge {
  margin: 7px 10px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
ul li .badge a {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Menu Header</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">4</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">3</a>
   </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Bank</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">19</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">7</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more clear

Comment: what do you want plz clearly

Comment: @Paulie_D it's how it gets printed from the server...

Comment: @MarkWilson I need the whole "box" to be clickeable

Comment: Do you want like this? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmufyng4/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the links display block and dont target the badge links by using descendant selector, and I also moved the badges up on the correct line by add ing bottom: 0;.

```
ul li > a {
   padding: 7px 10px;
   display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6a7643h9/

Comment: 1st, how could I miss that. 2nd <3

Answer (score 1):

Use `width: 100%;` for the link inside `li`

```
ul li a {
    padding: 7px 10px ;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /*20px = sum of left and right padding*/
}
```

**EDIT:**

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rmufyng4/3/)

Comment: this pushes the A block outside of it's parent and causes a bottom scrolling bar to appear

Comment: decrease the width to 97% or u can also use   width: calc(100% - 20px);
where 20px is double the padding value for left-right

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

```
 li {
   display: flex;
 }

 ul li a {
   flex:1;
 }
```

```css
a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border-left: 2px transparent solid;
  transition: background 0.10s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  /* so the badge follow the item if scrolling */
  display: flex;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-left: none;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
li:first-child:hover {
  border-left: none;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
li:hover {
  border-left: 2px #F27223 solid;
  background: white;
  transition: background 0s linear;
  /* vendorless fallback */
}
ul li a {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  fleX: 1;
}
ul li .badge {
  margin: 7px 10px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
ul li .badge a {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Menu Header</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">4</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">3</a>
   </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Bank</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">19</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="a">
      <span>Menu Item</span>
    </a>
    <span class="badge"><a href="a">7</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of JavaScript to wrap the whole thing in a div, and give it an onclick() event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: You are **overkilling** (_any help with exact word?_) the solution.

Comment: with all the respect, this is just crazy

Comment: It's overkill, sure. Perhaps it at least offers a different perspective on how things can be done.

Comment: we should not push for things that can be easily solved by CSS

Comment: Fair enough, duly noted